# Spring boot 2 @Transactional annotation makes Autowired fields null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired, transactional

I'm trying to use `@Transactional` annotation in a method on my service to lazily load a field. However using `@Transactional` on my Implementation class makes all autowired fields `null`.

Here is my implementation :

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

 /**
  * DefaultMapper.
  */
 @Autowired
 private DefaultMapper defaultMapper;

 /**
  * Resource service injection.
  */
 @Autowired
 private ResourceService resourceService;

 /**
  * UserRepository.
  */
 @Autowired
 private UserRepository userRepository;

 /**
  * Jwt Factory.
  */
 @Autowired
 private JwtService jwtService;

 @Override
 @Transactional
 public final UserDto findByLogin(final String login) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
 // user repository is null here when using @Transactional
  User user = this.userRepository.findByLogin(login)
   .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException(
    resourceService.getMessage(MessageBundle.EXCEPTION, "resource.notfound.user.login")
   ));
  UserDto userDto = defaultMapper.asUserDtoWithRoles(user);
  return userDto;
 }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Remove `final` from your method or set `spring.aop.proxy-target-class=false` in your `application.properties`. **NOTE:** This requires Spring Boot 1.5.3 or up to fully work!

Comment: Is the transactional context enabled in your spring application?

Comment: Make an transaction is most of the time useless during an reading action, are you sure you need an reading-transaction ?

Comment: Using spring.aop.proxy-target-class=false or removing final like @M.Deinum suggested fixes the issue. Can you please explain what really does  spring.aop.proxy-target-class=false ? thank you

Comment: @Zorglube I need a transaction to fetch data declared in Lazy fetching in the entity.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Transaction, amongst others, are applied using AOP, the default AOP mechanism in Spring is to use proxies. When using Spring Boot the proxy mode is set the class based proxies.

You can fix this in 1 of 2 ways.

1. Remove `final` from your method
2. Disable class based proxies by adding `spring.aop.proxy-target-class=false` to your `application.properties`

Now when you aded `@Transactional` this will lead to a proxy of your `UserServiceImpl` to be created, a class-based proxy to be exact. What happens is that a subclass is created for your `UserServiceImpl` and all methods are overriden to apply the `TransactionInterceptor`. However as your method is marked `final` the dynamically created class cannot override this method. As a result the method looks at field instances in the dynamically created proxy class which always will be `null`.

When removing `final` the method can be overridden, the behavior applied and it will look at the proper field instances (of the actual `UserServiceImpl` instead of the proxy).

When disabling class based proxies, you will get a JDK Dynamic Proxy which is basically a thin wrapper which implements all the interfaces your service implements. It applies the added behavior (transactions) and calls the actual service. There is no extension of the actual class needed and as such you can proxy final methods (as long as it is part of your interface).

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem working with Kotlin. When I added the `@Transactional` annotation to a method inside a service, I got a message saying `Methods annotated with '@Transactional' must be overridable` so I went ahead and marked both, the class and the method as `open`. Easy, right?! Well, not quite.

Although this compiles, I got the required repository as null at execution time. I was able to solve the problem in two ways:

1. Mark the class and **ALL of its methods** as `open`:

```
open class FooService(private val barRepository: BarRepository) {
    open fun aMethod(): Bar {
        ...
    }

    @Transactional
    open fun aTransactionalMethod(): Bar {
        ...
    }
}
```

This works but having all the methods in a class marked with `open` might look a bit odd, so I tried something else.

2. Declare an interface:

```
interface IFooService {
    fun aMethod(): Bar

    fun aTransactionalMethod(): Bar
}

open class FooService(private val barRepository: BarRepository) : IFooService {
    override fun aMethod(): Bar {
        ...
    }

    @Transactional
    override fun aTransactionalMethod(): Bar {
        ...
    }
}
```

This way you can still use the annotation since all the methods will be overridable and you won't need to use `open` everywhere.

Hope this helps =)

Comment: Right, I just tried to help people who might come from Kotlin looking for an answer for this issue, as it was my case. Usually, Kotlin and Java code are easily interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

Notice - final on the method you execute creates the problem, not necessary the method marked with @Transnational.
@Transnational annotation lead to dynamic creation of proxy objects. When having final method, it will not run on the proxy objects.